# C++ объединение интервалов по времени

Tags: c++, qt

Всем привет. Прошу помоч, а то с вложенными циклами каша в голове уже. Суть задачи такая, есть зона структура **zone** в которую входит массив подзон структура **sub_zone**, массив **sub_zone** включает в себя 2 временных интервала **QDateTime start и QDateTime end**; Структура вложенностей такая:

```
typedef struct
{
   // текущий интервал
   QDateTime start;
   QDateTime end;
} sTimeInterval;

typedef struct
{
   QList<sTimeInterval> intervals; // множество интервалов
} sVariant;

typedef struct
{
   QList<sVariant> variants; // множество вариантов
} sSubZone;

typedef struct
{
   QList<sSubZone> subZones; // множество подзон
} sZone;
```

Предположим, что объект структуры **Zone** **zones** уже заполнен подзонами **их 6 штук** в каждую из которых уже включено множество интервалов. Т.е уже всё заполнено. **Что нужно?** Создать новую структуру **Zone resultZones** и заполнить её так, что бы массив подзон в данном случае их **6** включали друг друга. **Т.е по циклу берется сначала последняя подзона, в данном случае 6-я** и **объединяются интервал 6 объединяется с  5, 4, 3, 2 , 1 **  данный результат объединения записывается в resultZones** которую мы создали. Объединение на каждой итерации происходит с помощью функции **которая уже написана** **TimeIntervals intervalsUnion("интервал 6 подзоны", "интервал 5 подзоны")**, как прошли все интервалы подзоны по циклу далее уже аргументы функции **(5,4)** подзоны и тд. В функции происходит объединение интервалов в цикле как я указал выше и возвращается интервал который записывается в подзону 6. Далее уже берется 5 подзона и объединяется с 4, 3, 2, 1 и записывается в структуру **resultZones** и тд пока не пройдём все подзоны.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, уже написанная функция `intervalsUnion` принимает два объекта какого типа ­— `TimeIntervals`, `Sub_zone` или `Zone`?

Comment: TimeIntervals принимают

Comment: В каждой подзоне одинаковое число интервалов или необязательно?

Comment: Вероятностей одинаково в данном случае. а интервалы так. Ищем минимальный  int minIntervalSize = qMin(variant1.intervals.size(), variant2.intervals.size()); а затем берем его как за основу сколько раз пройтись. Что бы не получилось, так что в одном закончилось, а в другом еще есть.

Comment: Правда же, что должно получиться `resultZones.sub_zones.size() == 1`?

Comment: Я немного подправил структуры в коде, должно быть более понятно, так как там был косяк. По сути есть одна зона sZone в нём может быть несколько подзон sSubZone, в свою очередь каждая подзона имеет список вариантов sVariant (их везде одинаково) и каждый вариант имеет свой список интервалов sTimeInterval (их может быть у каждой вероятности по разному).